# jQuery selector mistake

Tags: jquery

I was using jQuery UI Dialog and jQuery to select a "radio" button.

I have 2 dialog, one for "calculator", another for "expert_mode".

However, when I select a `'input[value="simple"]'` under calculator, it also affects an `input` under expert_mode with the same name, how to fix that??

Followings are my codes:

This is my HTML (simplified):

```
<div name="widget">
    <div name="calculator">
        <input name="mode" value="a" type="radio" **checked="checked"**/>
        <input name="mode" value="b" type="radio"/>
        <input name="mode" value="c" type="radio"/>
    </div>
    <div name="expert">
        <input name="mode" value="simple" type="radio"/>
        <input name="mode" value="advanced" type="radio"/>
        <input name="mode" value="custom" type="radio"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var widget=$('div[name="widget"]');
var calculator=widget.find('div[name="calculator"]');
var expert=widget.find('div[name="expert"]');

calculator.dialog();
expert.dialog();
```

Then, when I do this:

```
expert.find('input[value="simple"]').attr('checked',true);
```

It becomes:

```
<div name="widget">
    <div name="calculator">
        <input name="mode" value="a" type="radio"/> ***Here, "checked" disappear!!***
        <input name="mode" value="b" type="radio"/>
        <input name="mode" value="c" type="radio"/>
    </div>
    <div name="expert">
        <input name="mode" value="simple" type="radio" checked="checked"/>
        <input name="mode" value="advanced" type="radio"/>
        <input name="mode" value="custom" type="radio"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `name` of your `input` elements, not your jQuery. As all of the radio buttons have the same name, they are treated as one group, and only one radio button can be checked per group. You will have to change the `name` of one set of radio buttons, for example (simplified):

```
<div name="calculator">
    <input name="mode" value="a" type="radio"/>
</div>
<div name="expert">
    <input name="expertMode" value="simple" type="radio" checked="checked"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You are correct.<br/>
I forgot that only one radio, which shares a same name, can be checked at one time.<br/>
Thank you!!<br/>
(so, this is not a problem about jquery at all...)